# FLV video not running in browser with no error in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to deploy my ASP.NET Application which is currently running on Windows Server 2003 32bit and IIS6 to a new Server running Windows Server 2008 R2 and IIS7.
My application uses ASP.NET version 4.0 and is working fine on 2003 machine.

My problem is:

**I have deployed the application and it is working fine except that the .flv video is not playing in browser**

**I have added all required mime settings but still no luck**

when i try to run the video i don't get any error just a blank screen showing no video.

Same configuration is working on previous machine and the new server is also able to play the video when run from the earlier machine.

Please if you have any solution help me out.

---

I have just found an Event Error entry that gets logged when i try to run the video. It is as follows:

```
    Event code: 3005 
    Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred.
    Event time: 10/9/2012 1:07:14 PM 
    Event time (UTC): 10/9/2012 8:07:14 PM 
    Event ID: 09303bdb94d64235a5ab118955416895 
    Event sequence: 12 
    Event occurrence: 1 
    Event detail code: 0 

    Application information: 
        Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/BYPL-1-129942868205521131 
        Trust level: Full 
        Application Virtual Path: /BYPL 
        Application Path: F:\BYPL_Simulator_26_Sept_2012\ 
        Machine name: BYPL-APP-SERVER 

    Process information: 
        Process ID: 2536 
        Process name: w3wp.exe 
        Account name: BYPL-APP-SERVER\Administrator 

    Exception information: 
        Exception type: HttpException 
        Exception message: Could not load type 'FLVStreaming'.
        at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean  throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
        at System.Web.Configuration.HandlerFactoryCache.GetTypeWithAssert(String type)
        at System.Web.Configuration.HandlerFactoryCache.GetHandlerType(String type)
        at System.Web.Configuration.HandlerFactoryCache..ctor(String type)
        at System.Web.HttpApplication.GetFactory(String type)
        at           System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
        at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

    Request information: 
        Request URL: http://localhost/BYPL/Administrator/MeterManagement/Installation/video/634655271233125000.flv
        Request path: /BYPL/Administrator/MeterManagement/Installation/video/634655271233125000.flv 
        User host address: 127.0.0.1 
        User: bypl 
        Is authenticated: True 
        Authentication Type: Forms 
        Thread account name: BYPL-APP-SERVER\Administrator 

        Thread information: 
        Thread ID: 5 
        Thread account name: BYPL-APP-SERVER\Administrator 
        Is impersonating: False 
        Stack trace:    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
        at System.Web.Configuration.HandlerFactoryCache.GetTypeWithAssert(String type)
        at System.Web.Configuration.HandlerFactoryCache.GetHandlerType(String type)
        at System.Web.Configuration.HandlerFactoryCache..ctor(String type)
        at System.Web.HttpApplication.GetFactory(String type)
        at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
        at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

I added a file named FLVStreaming.cs in the app_code folder and then re-published the application and the file contained the following code:

```
using System.Web;
public class FLVStreaming : IHttpHandler
{   // FLV header
public FLVStreaming()
{}
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{ try{
        int pos;
        int length;
        // Check start parameter if present
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(context.Request.FilePath);
        using (FileStream fs = new   FileStream(context.Server.MapPath(filename), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            string qs = context.Request.Params["start"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(qs))
            {
                pos = 0;
                length = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                pos = Convert.ToInt32(qs);
                length = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length - pos) + _flvheader.Length;
            }
            // Add HTTP header stuff: cache, content type and length        
            context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
            context.Response.Cache.SetLastModified(DateTime.Now);
            context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "video/x-flv");
            context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", length.ToString());
            // Append FLV header when sending partial file
            if (pos > 0)
            {
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(_flvheader, 0, _flvheader.Length);
                fs.Position = pos;
            }
            // Read buffer and write stream to the response stream
            const int buffersize = 16384;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];
            int count = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffersize);
            while (count > 0)
            {
                if (context.Response.IsClientConnected)
                {
                    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                    count = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffersize);
                }
                else
                {
                    count = -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
public bool IsReusable
{   get { return true; }
}
private static byte[] HexToByte(string hexString)
{ 
    byte[] returnBytes = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < returnBytes.Length; i++)
        returnBytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
    return returnBytes;
}
}
```

It appears like this file gets converted into a .ddl file and this dll file version was not matching according to the Machine architecture.